# I'm trying to access a partition made on my internal har disk from windows that is installed on the ssd, but windows doesn't reconizes it

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, windows, ssd, storage

I have ubuntu 22.04.02 installed on my internal 1tb hard disk and windows 10 installed on my 128gb internal ssd. I wanted to use a section of the hard disk to store files that i use on windows, so i resized the hard disk space (using the live version of ubuntu installed on my usb) and i created 400gb of free unallocated space. Then i partitioned, from the ubuntu installed on my pc, all of the 400gb of free unallocated space. When i reboot the computer  and start windows i can't see my 400gb partition in the disk management software. I tried to format the partition whit a bunch of different formats (including NTFS and FAT) but the situation doesn't change at all. Everything is showen in the attached images.

[Hard disk viewed from disk software in ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmV5R.png)

[SSD viewed from disk software in ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRxqf.png)

[Situation in Windows disk management software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R88GY.png)

Now the 400gb section is not partitioned but the situation doesn't change if i partition it.

Comment: Does gdisk show any issues? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` Use gdisk and verify partitions are correct with p, or v to review issues,  and use w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. That should update primary, backup & protective MBR. Details:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html